# How to scale a node.js app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, scaling, multiplayer

I'm currently building a small multiplayer game like agar.io with node.js and socket.io. It's early in development, but I have some questions about scaling.

When there are less than 80 people playing the game, they all play together and everything works fine. But what if there are 1,000 players online? I think I'll need to:

- Split players across different "rooms" (e.g. one room = 100 players), otherwise the game would be too difficult to play.
- And probably split the "rooms" across different servers (e.g. one server = 5 rooms) for better performances.

However I have no idea how any of this works... Any advice or ressources to share on these subjects? I'm currently hosting the game on Heroku if that makes any difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to partition with the rooms and namespaces concepts in socket.io:

- http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

You'll also need to configure socket.io for multiple nodes:

- http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

On Heroku, you'll need to enable session affinity ('sticky sessions'):

- https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/4/25/session-affinity-ga

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! "rooms and namespaces" is perfect to solve my first problem. However I'm not sure to see how "nodes & affinity" will work for the scaling. Would there be a simpler solution?

Comment: FYI I don't need the players to communicate between each other if they are in different rooms, even less if they are on different servers.